# Как сдвинуть массив влево?

Tags: c, массивы, циклы

Есть функция сдвига массива на 6 позиций вправо, а как изменить именно этот цикл чтобы сдвиг был влево?

```
int numbersShifting(int* arr, int size) {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        temp = arr[size - 1];
        for (int j = size - 2; j >= 0; --j) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        }
        arr[0] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну уже ведь обсуждали этот вопрос, что **так** сдвигать вообще не стоит... Кстати, а почему именно на 6? На N вы не в состоянии переделать? :)

Comment: @Harry да мне не важно на сколько сдвигать массив, мне нужно чтобы именно этот цикл сдвигал его влево, хотя это и не очень правильно, но по-другому мне не нужно

Comment: Вы же понимаете что если сдвинуть далеко направо, то это будет выглядеть ка сдвиг налево?

Comment: @Harry, быстро сдвигать сложно (хотя и красиво). Люди предпочитают простые понятные решения. :(

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Насчет сдвига вправо как сдвига в результате влево я писал несколько дней назад, когда этот вопрос задавался в прошлый раз. Не помогает!

Comment: Кстати, у вашей функции, возвращающей `int`, нет `return`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, вот вам сдвиг на 6 позиций влево (только для `size >= 6`):

```
void numbersShifting(int* arr, int size) {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size-6; ++i) {
        temp = arr[size - 1];
        for (int j = size - 2; j >= 0; --j) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        }
        arr[0] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

```
int numbersShifting(int* arr, int size) {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        temp = arr[0];
        for (int j = 1; j < size-1; ++j) {
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        }
        arr[size-1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]